# How I can get rid of the release candidate Neo4j 2.3.0-M03 and go back to the latest stable version?

Tags: neo4j

My database is empty, no danger of loosing any data.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n) return count(n);
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
1 row
156 ms
```

Comment: How did you installed 2.3.0-M03 version?

Comment: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-3-milestone-3-release/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your production server, you should use 'http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' as deb repository.

First uninstall previous version

- apt-get remove --purge neo4j
- change repository to stable one
- apt-get install neo4j

Comment: I am using hosting by AWS. I am not downloading.

Comment: I am using the installation steps from here: http://danielwertheim.se/2014/08/17/getting-neo4j-up-and-running-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-hyper-v/comment-page-1/

Comment: And I put this line deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo testing/ in the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list

Comment: I have no clue where the 2.3.0 directory is in my server. Can't recreate the EC2 server since I have also other things there.

Comment: apt-get remove --purge neo4j succeeded and apt-get install neo4j succeeded, now I have to figure out why the server does not restart.

Comment: @LDB share your log files (console.log and message.log) with us

Comment: Don't know where these two log files are located.

Comment: From console.log: org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/ubuntu/data/neo4j-data/graph.db Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/ubuntu/data/neo4j-data/graph.db

Comment: OK, I found the problem, my data directory where graph.db was located was a mess. I clean it up and the server restarted.